# delete attributes nested within an array of objects Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to remove the attribute `nested1` that is inside the `attr7_nested` in a massive way, I don't need to persist this data in the bank, just store it in a variable to send to a log file.

example file follows:

```
[{
  "attr1": 120,
  "attr2": 24,
  "attr3": 11400,
  "attr4": "Caixa",
  "attr5": 2000000,
  "attr6": 1744000,
  "attr7_nested": {
    "nested1": 1,
    "nested2": "Essential",
    "nested3": "med",
    "nested4": "Med"
  }
},
{
  "attr1": 120,
  "attr2": 24,
  "attr3": 11400,
  "attr4": "Caixa",
  "attr5": 2000000,
  "attr6": 1744000,
  "attr7_nested": {
    "nested1": 1,
    "nested2": "Ess",
    "nested3": "med",
    "nested4": "Med"
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `array` is the array containing the nested hashes from your question than the following would remove the `nested1` keys from all nested `attr7_nested` hashes:

```
array.each { |hash| hash[:attr7_nested].delete(:nested1) }
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend for your help, I'm a beginner in ruby, very good